# Run local DynamoDB spark job without EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I want to run local Dynamodb spark job without using EMR cluster,
that read data from some table and write it to parquet / CSV file.
I didn't found any spark-dynamo connector that supports that, maybe you have any ideas?

My code sample:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object copyDynamoTable extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("test")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  val jobConf = new JobConf(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  jobConf.set("dynamodb.servicename", "dynamodb")
  jobConf.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", "hen.poc.client") // Pointing to DynamoDB table
  jobConf.set("dynamodb.endpoint", "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
  jobConf.set("dynamodb.regionid", "us-east-1")
  jobConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.read", "1")
  jobConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.read.percent", "1")
  jobConf.set("dynamodb.version", "2011-12-05")

  jobConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")
  jobConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")

  val orders = spark.sparkContext.hadoopRDD(jobConf, classOf[DynamoDBInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[DynamoDBItemWritable])

  println(orders.count)
```

I received the following exception:

```
18/09/05 17:06:41 INFO util.TaskCalculator: Cluster has 1 active nodes.
18/09/05 17:06:41 WARN util.ClusterTopologyNodeCapacityProvider: Exception when trying to determine instance types
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /mnt/var/lib/info/job-flow.json
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.util.ClusterTopologyNodeCapacityProvider.readJobFlowJsonString(ClusterTopologyNodeCapacityProvider.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.util.ClusterTopologyNodeCapacityProvider.getCoreNodeMemoryMB(ClusterTopologyNodeCapacityProvider.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.util.TaskCalculator.getMaxMapTasks(TaskCalculator.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBUtil.calcMaxMapTasks(DynamoDBUtil.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.AbstractDynamoDBInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractDynamoDBInputFormat.java:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1162)
    at com.data.spark.dynamodb.copyDynamoTable$.delayedEndpoint$com$riskified$data$spark$dynamodb$copyDynamoTable$1(copyDynamoTable.scala:30)
    at com.data.spark.dynamodb.copyDynamoTable$delayedInit$body.apply(copyDynamoTable.scala:9)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.data.spark.dynamodb.copyDynamoTable$.main(copyDynamoTable.scala:9)
    at com.data.spark.dynamodb.copyDynamoTable.main(copyDynamoTable.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a file that is present on an EMR cluster. This is to try to determine what instance type it is running against to determine some job settings such as memory. Obviously running locally you wouldn't have this file so this is expected.

Please follow the bellow thread :

[emr/github.com/issues/50](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/issues/50)

Comment: Sure, but there is any way to run this code locally on my pc and not on EMR cluster?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Your Code should run on your local PC without any problem in case of the Exception also. You can also explicitly handle the exception.